# Problems in the deploy-to-fabric-multi-org tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm having problems following the Hyperledger composer tutorial:
**Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)**

I was following this tutorial 2 weeks ago and now I noticed that some steps have changed. I assume that is because of the new composer version.

Until step 8 I was able to follow the tutorial without any problems. It was when I arrived at step 9 (*Importing the business network cards for the Hyperledger Fabric administrator for Org1*), that I was not able to move on.

When executing the command:

```
composer card import -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1.card --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-undefined" for connection type "undefined". Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'-Cannot find module 'composer-connector-undefined'
Command failed
```

The truth is that I do not understand what may be happening, it's a very strange error... **Also mention that the command is outdated, since the --card has now been replaced by --name.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by:

1. making sure all of `composer-client`, `composer-common`, `composer-admin`, `composer-playground`, `composer-rest-server`, and `composer-cli` are on the latest version, i.e. 0.19.0 at the moment.
2. regenerate the `trade-network.bna`.
3. remove all the cards and credentials before setting up the network:
   `rm *.card
   rm alice/*.pem
   rm bob/*.pem`

That all said, the `trade-network` uses a different ChainCode from the one that's installed by `byfn.sh` (i.e. `mycc`). I don't know why they don't update this tutorial to match the 2. That's still a mystery to me.

Comment: I just updated the composer to the latest version as you said ( https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/managing/updating-composer ) and finally worked. I assume that being such recent changes still have aspects to update.